# formula to convert Lat and Long to x & Y in an Image

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, openstreetmap

HI

I have a Map Image that I got from OpenstreetMap(Osmarender Image ) .My question is

how to convert geographic coordinates to the co-ordinates of my picture (that is in pixels on X and Y on a picture). That is I receive geographic coordinates and it is necessary for me to draw this point on my picture.

Is there any API availabel in QT for processing this type of Map Problem

Comment: Could've just Googled it : http://www.google.co.in/search?q=convert+lat+long+to+x+y&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Whether it's available in QT I don't know. Maybe someone with QT experience could help you. Or, just Google it!

Comment: @Nav - So long as they aren't duplicates, asking even 'easy' questions  on SO helps people with the same problem find a great answer. Sometimes, it's hard to figure out what to search _for_ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer I was expecting can be found at 
[Convert Lat/Longs to X/Y Co-ordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953150/convert-lat-longs-to-x-y-co-ordinates)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Check out the Proj4 library](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/). You need to map the lat-longs to an XY coordinate system (e.g. UTM) and then map this to pixel space. Don't think Qt has anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

Check the code for my [mapsnap](http://bit.ly/x2-mapsnap) example, in particular MapModel::draw() function. If you know the zoom level of the OpenStreetMap rendered image and the tile offset, it is a matter of implementing the [slippy map tile](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#C.2FC.2B.2B) approach.